# Using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() for Gremlin.net ResultSet, object properties are null or empty (c#)

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, vertex

Using Gremlin.Net (3.4.6) and CosmosDB/Graph
Upon query, ResultSet of dynamic type is serialized. It is thereafter deserialized to a specific List<> of type Person. Basic vertex values are there, however, the properties' values are empty. 
I've tried various solutions (including using a Wrapper) without success (the Person objects are null). 
Using JSON property attribute makes no difference.

```
Gremlin.Net.Driver.ResultSet<dynamic> result = await ExecuteQuery();
string pList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);     
List<Person> people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(pList);
```

The pList looks like this:
[Note that properties members have values in the JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grBwG.png)

Person class is defined as:

```
public class Person : VertexBase
    {
        [JsonProperty("Name")]
        public VertexProperty<string, NameMeta> Name { get; set; }       
        public string[] PhoneNumbers { get; set; }    
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {         

        }

    }
```

What is the right way of doing this? Surely it should be something reasonably simple to get at the nested dictionary of properties. The examples do not show *deserialization*.

Comment: Please paste the pList string

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, and I worked around it by explicitly adding a member to my class (`Person` class in your case) that would contain the Properties dictionary:

```
    public class PropertyKeyValuePair
    {
        public string Id;
        public string Value;
    }

    public class Person
    {
        // Other fields
        // ...
        public Dictionary<string, PropertyKeyValuePair[]> properties;
    }
```

The `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` function now should be able to deserialize the properties into the `properties` member.